# Adding html and js to wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Can somebody please point me on how to/where to include custom javascript and HTML code to achieve (for example)something like this ( https://codepen.io/steveg3003/pen/ALXbYN) on my site..for example, I would like my heading on my website to look like that and to have that kind of effect.
I am familiar with editing my child theme by adding custom CSS, but I never had a situation where I must add HTML and js code as well..so I'm bit confused how and where should I do that, I tried but failed.
I'm using Oceanwp and Elementor btw.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a custom plugin. Might sound complicated at the beginning, but it really isn't. Documentation is pretty clear and helpful:
[Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin)

Giving a complete answer to this question or writing it for you would take pretty long. But as a starting point to play around, create a folder in your plugins directory and create a .php file in there containing

```
    <?php

    // This is needed so Wordpress can read/find the plugin
    /*
    Plugin Name: XY
    Description: Something
    Version: 0.01
    Author: Author
    Author URI: https://stackoverflow.com
    */

    // If this file is called directly, abort (security stuff)
    if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
        die;
    }


    // Load scripts and stylesheets
    function enqueue_load_xy() {
         wp_enqueue_style( 'load-some-style', plugins_url( '/css/some_style.css', __FILE__ ) );
         wp_enqueue_script('load-some-script', plugins_url( '/js/some_script.js'));
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_load_xy' );


    // Create a shortcode that can be used on any site with [your_shortcode]
    function function_name()
    {

        $function_name_output .= '

        HTML and output goes here

            ';

    return $function_name_output;

    }
    add_shortcode( 'your_shortcode', 'function_name' );
```

You'll get what this does once you read a bit in the codex (basically load a stylesheet from a css subdirectory and a .js file from a js subdirectory of your plugin and create a shortcode to be used on any site).

You could actually copy the js, css and html from your fiddle in the according places and should be good. Please make sure you don't copy the style for body etc. though and use your own prefixes so you don't break exising styles or plugins.

Also be sure to test it on a local or other test installation of wordpress as wrong code in plugins can quickly lead to errors that can be seen by everyone.